# Unix -- Time zone issue

Tags: unix, datetime, timezone-offset

I need to predict the next run of a daily job. For example, if my job runs everyday at 1:00:00 am, and my sysdate is Nov 7 11:20:00 am, then my next run will be at Nov 8 1:00:00 am

The below logic helps me to achieve the desired results. However, when i convert the date after adding no. days to the start date, unix considers the daylight saving and converts from PDT timezone to PST timezone and gives me a time lag of 1 hour. Instead of getting  Nov 8 1:00:00 am, I am getting  Nov 8 00:00:00 am as output.

I want to derive date without the day light savings. Can someone help me achieve this logic in UNIX?

```
CURR_DATE=`date "+%s"`    
START_DATE=`date -d "19OCT2014 01:00:00" "+%s"` #start date when the job was run first    
diff_quo=$(((($CURR_DATE - $START_DATE) / (86400))))    
diff_quo=$(($diff_quo * 86400))    
new_datetime=$(($START_DATE + $diff_quo + 86400 ))   
DERIVED_DATE=`date -d"@$new_datetime" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S"`
```

Thanks,
Ekata

Comment: why all that complicated fiddling when you could just have `date --date='01:00 tomorrow'`? If you don't want DST involved, then use UTC/GMT

Comment: Got your point. I have just added example of daily run. In my actual code, interval is not fixed, it can be 1 day, 1 hour, 1 min. Also, if my sysdate is Nov 7 12:30 am,  date --date='01:00 tomorrow' <<< this is not going to work